# PhpStorm keyboard shortcut to extend text selection over next line

Tags: phpstorm

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut in PhpStorm to allow me to select or extend a selection of multiple contiguous lines. I know about <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + W</kbd> to select the parent/containing node, but how can I select the next sibling node?

Say for example I have:

```
foreach($somevar as $name=>$value) {
    $temp1 = $name . "_1";
    $temp2 = $name . "_2";
    echo $value;
}
```

With <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + W</kbd> I can very easily extend the selection to include the whole of the line with `$temp1` on it, but if I use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + W</kbd> to extend beyond this, I'll get everything within the `foreach`.

If I have the line with `$temp1` already selected, how can I extend the selection to include line `$temp2` without also selecting `echo $value`?

Comment: A standard `Shift+Down` perhaps? But that will depend on caret position (better be at first column in the line) to work properly. I do not see any special/dedicated actions for "select next line" (at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions`)

Comment: There is dedicated action for "Select Line at Caret" (which does not have shortcut by default in Default keymap) -- you may try using it instead of `Ctrl + Shift + W` -- maybe it will position caret in a more convenient way for selecting additional lines above/below current one.